# What is the purpose of setNamespaceAware in DocumentBuilder?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Would someone please let in which condition should I set  `setNamespaceAware` to `true` or `false`

According to documentation `Specifies that the parser produced by this code will provide support for XML namespaces.`

However if I set that to true, for XML tags with Namespace it gives error.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory document_builder_factory = null;
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
document_builder_factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
document_builder_factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

try{
    Text text = new Text();

    text.set("<h:test>10</h:test>");
    builder = document_builder_factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(text.toString())));;
    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("h:test").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

}catch (Exception e){

}
```

I get the following error if `setNamespaceAware` is set to `true`.

> [Fatal Error] :1:9: The prefix "h" for element "h:test" is not bound.

If I don't set it, I get the value without any error.

Comment: [`DocumentBuilderFactory#setNamespaceAware`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any disadvantages to setNamespaceAware(true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790117/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-setnamespaceawaretrue)

Comment: @JonnyHenly I checked that answer however I am still not clear when to set this to true and when to false. Can you give me an example

Answer (score 4):

In a non-namespace-aware document, colons are a valid character of the node name, so you could, for instance, have an element <h:test>.

Such elements before XML namespaces were introduced would work fine. So for backward compatibility, when support for namespaces was introduced, the only way to keep that code working without changes, was to make namespace awareness false by default, because <h:test> is not legal in a namespace aware document.